# How to deal with constant error checking in C?

Tags: c, error-handling, readability

In C, I am calling many functions having to check if they worked. The code gets ~3x bigger because of it! An example:

```
char *myStr = malloc(sizeof(char));
if (!myStr)
    return NULL;
```

Is there a more readable way to code calling and error-checking in C? Or is this just the way the cookie crumbles?

I have tried the following macro. But it does not seem idiomatic in C, nor it worked -- the mistake was pointed by "Key Y-N".

```
#define TRY_EXCEPT(try_statement, except_condition, except_statement) try_statement##if(except_condition){except_statement}
```

Edit: This is the density of calling and error-checking I meant.

```
if (!varNames)
    goto exit_fail;

struct dynStr *asmCode = dynStr_create();
if (!asmCode)
    goto exit_fail;

int rc;
rc = dynStr_append(asmCode, ".data\n");
if (!rc)
    goto exit_fail;

char *varName;
for (size_t i = 0; (varName = daStr_getString(varNames, i)); i++) {
    rc = dynStr_append(asmCode, "DD ");
    if (!rc)
        goto free_and_exit;

    rc = dynStr_append(asmCode, varName);
    if (!rc)
        goto free_and_exit;

    rc = dynStr_append(asmCode, "\n");
    if (!rc)
        goto free_and_exit;
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253226/discussion-on-question-by-gabriel-silva-schilive-how-to-deal-with-constant-error); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd condense it like so:

```
if (!(rc = dynStr_append(asmCode, "DD ")) 
    || !(rc = dynStr_append(asmCode, varName)) 
    || !(rc = dynStr_append(asmCode, "\n"))) {
    goto free_and_exit;
}
```

Or use another variable:

```
int exit_stat = !(rc = dynStr_append(asmCode, "DD ")) 
                || !(rc = dynStr_append(asmCode, varName)) 
                || !(rc = dynStr_append(asmCode, "\n"));

if (exit_stat) {
    goto free_and_exit;
}
```

Or simply remove the assignment to `rc`:

```
if (!dynStr_append(asmCode, "DD ")) 
    || !dynStr_append(asmCode, varName) 
    || !dynStr_append(asmCode, "\n"))) {
    goto free_and_exit;
}
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of a "bool" variable like that! I did think about the last example, but I feared it was bad, like, too cluttered. But here it seems good. Thank you for giving so many alternatives!

Comment: *Or simply remove the assignment to rc*  If you hadn't put that in there, I'd be sorely temped to downvote - putting assignments into if-statements is bug-prone enough.  Cramming multiple assignments into a complex if-statement is practically begging for bugs.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, and it looks hideous. But OP had an assignment in the `for` loop, so I just went with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can economise by recognising the LF is not so special. (And, pay attention to where you branch after a presumed dynamic allocation.)

```
struct dynStr *asmCode = dynStr_create();
if (!asmCode)
    goto exit_fail;

if( !dynStr_append(asmCode, ".data") )
    goto free_and_exit; // memory leak fixed...

char *varName;
for( size_t i = 0; (varName = daStr_getString(varNames, i)); i++ ) {
    if( !dynStr_append(asmCode, "\nDD ") // Notice the LF prepended
    ||  !dynStr_append(asmCode, varName) )
        goto free_and_exit;
}
if( !dynStr_append(asmCode, "\n") )
    goto free_and_exit;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! The idea is pretty and I have seen it in Linux kernel, which means I can blame other people. I like it. But I am sorry for my ignorance: what is *LF*? BTW, sorry for leaking...

Comment: `LF` == "line feed", a.ka. "newline"... Suggest you learn the conventional names of the ASCII characters...